# how to get how much percentage video is watched by user

Tags: c#, asp.net, youtube-javascript-api

Is there any way to get **how many percentage** of video is being watched by user on 
youtube?
Using javascript or any thing else in asp.net using C#.
Is it possible by Jquery or javascript?

Comment: I don't know about the code. But simple logic is: add the total duration of the video in one variable and the current duration of the video in another. Then simply calculate the percentage.

Comment: how do i get current duration?

Comment: Do you get a xml file named gdata or something?

Answer (score 1):

Use `player.getCurrentTime();`

This will give you the current time of the video. Divide it with the total duration of the video and multiply by 100.